# Determine which QuerySetAPI method is called

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-queryset

I am trying to log overridden calls to `QuerySetAPI` 
Say I am calling 
`Example.objects.filter(id=1)`
and I have following code in `Models.py`

```
objects = MyManager()
```

and in `MyManager` I have-

```
class MyManager(Manager): 
   def get_query_set(self):
       # logging stuff I am doing
       return super(MyManager, self).get_query_set()
```

How do I get the method name (i.e. `filter` here) in `MyManager->get_query_set()`?
Is there a way to do that without using `inspect stack()`?

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` comes from the `QuerySet` object that `get_query_set` from the Manager returns.
The filter function is there:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/04e8d890aec8e996d568565555164a27a6a76057/django/db/models/query.py#L778

Comment: I caanot understand how do I inject it in `get_query_set`?

Comment: You should roll your own QuerySet class that logs calls to filter for example. Then you can create a manager out of that QuerySet as explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset